# extjs 4 TreeStore and combobox

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a treestore backing a tree view of financial accounts which works fine. I now want to create a combobox to allow individual records to choose an account based on its flattened name. So, 
for example, if my account tree looks like:
assets
   bank
     current
     deposit
expenses
   car
     fuel

etc,
I would have a combobox containing:
  assets-bank-current
  assets-bank-deposit
  expenses-car-fuel
and so on.
These names are already available as a field in the account  record. The problem is that a combobox won't allow a treestore rather than a store as backing. 
At the moment, I am using a second normal store and loading it independently from the database. This is ugly, and when I move towards allowing the account tree to be modified, I will have all sorts of grief keeping both stores in sync.

So, is there a nice way of either:
- making a treestore work in a combobox
   or
- keeping a treestore and a normal store in sync, e.g. having the normal store proxy through the treestore?

Answer (score 0):

call `<comboboxstore>.reload();` in your `datachanged` -event of the `treestore`

(assuming you load the Data via `load`-event and `AutoLoad=false` at least at comboboxstore)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I don't see how this helps me. What's 'OnReadData' there's no ReadData method or event....I want to be able to use the treestore as the backing store for the combobox, possibly with the aid of some kind of adapter class. I suppose I could do this by creating a memory store and having the treestore update it every time it changes, but I'd still need to manually implement all the conversion stuff. I'm kind of hoping there's something already there  I can use, since I'd have thought this was a common enough requirement.

Comment: oh ok im using Ext.Net to be honest - i think it's the `load`event then - maybe the `datachanged`is even better for your requirement